# Missing the "Security & Privacy" option in settings

Tags: settings

Using elementary OS Freya 0.3.2 (64bit).

Comment: What did you do last

Comment: @SuiciDoga - I removed zeitgeist. But after finding out the missing option i reinstalled it. It didn't fix (of course).

Comment: This is provided by a switchboard plug. I am currently doing some maintenance on my system but once I'm finished I'll tell you which one.

Comment: @RolandiXor - Thank You for your help bro, but I already found it
`switchboard-plug-security-privacy`.

Comment: @GibreelAbdullah sorry for not following up - took so long with what I was doing I'd forgotten to update you.

Answer (score 2):

OP found the missing plug:

> @RolandiXor - Thank You for your help bro, but I already found it
>   switchboard-plug-security-privacy.